# Javascript function is undefined only in IE11

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer, undefined

I'm trying to use a template but just realized that the javascript doesn't work at all in IE.

It fails in several places but here is the first one:

I have this tag, immediately before my `</html>`:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
        navbarToggleSidebar();
        navActivePage();
    });
</script>
```

The exception says, "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'navbarToggleSidebar' is undefined occurred"

The javascript file that came with this template was minimized as uses some cracy javascript markup that I've never seen and do not understand. But when I do a find in the whole solution for navbarToggleSidebar I only find this:

```
JkW7: function (t, e, n) {
            "use strict";
            Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
                value: !0
            });
            var i = (n("PExH"), n("juYr"), n("6wzU"), n("e9iq"), n("aWFY"));
            ! function (t) {
                t.keys().map(t)
            }(n("pax0")), Object.assign(window, {
                masonryBuild: i.a,
                navbarToggleSidebar: i.c,
                navActivePage: i.b
            })
        },
```

I can post the whole file somewhere (just tell me where, it's too long to paste here) if that's helpful because this is clearly just a piece of a huge js thing that I don't understand at all. I like to think I'm fairly decent with js and jquery and this looks greek to me. And it all works beautifully in Chrome and FF.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

Thanks!!

Comment: what kind of module bundler are you using in the project?. The snippet you posted doesn't look like a src file. It looks like a build js. You can use jsfiddle  
 https://jsfiddle.net/ to recreate your scenario.

Comment: Object.assign doest work in IE11 make sure you load some polyfill above the main script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well n is a callback function t is an array or a list of some kind most likely; so in order for you to figure out what is actually happening in the function you have to figure out where the function was actually invoked. It is much easier to find out what library was used and see if it is hosted anywhere in a non-minified version.
Sometimes this is done intentionally in order to protect developers from other people having an easy time engineering their solutions to programming problems. 
Basically in order for anyone to figure out what the function actually does, you would have to print the entire page library, then trace through it, then when you are done after about a month you will have your answer.
Arrays, callback functions, as well as a probably system variable and object literals are used in that function.